# Is there a way to use a bootable USB stick on a Mac?

Tags: windows, mac, ssd, multi-boot, boot-camp

I'm trying to upgrade my SSD firmware on my Mac, but it won't boot using the bootable USB stick that the Samsung SSD Magician software made since it's DOS.

Is there a way to boot from it? I have Windows 7 installed via Boot Camp in the machine.

Comment: What is the product ID of your Mac's HDD?

Comment: Can you get another USB stick?

Answer (score 3):

Intel-based Macs support starting from an external USB storage device's volume that:

- Has been formatted with a
  [GUID](http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?path=Mac/10.5/en/9014.html)
  partition type
- Contains an installation of Mac OS X 10.4.5 or later, or Mac OS X
  10.5 or later, which is compatible with (or [shipped
  with](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1159)) the Mac that the USB
  device is connected to.

Note: You [should not use](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2186) a version of Mac OS X that is earlier ("older") than the version your Mac shipped with.
To start from a USB storage device that meets the above requirements, connect the device, then select it in Startup Disk preferences. Or, connect the device, restart, and immediately press and hold the Option key to access [Startup Manager](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1310).

### Notes

- It may be necessary to connect the USB storage device to an external
  power supply, depending on its power requirements.
- If you're using a MacBook or MacBook Pro, try using a different USB
  port if you cannot startup from the external USB storage device.
- On a MacBook Air, the computer [may shutdown
  automatically](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS2055) as a preventive
  measure if a USB device with issues is connected, or if the USB port
  on the MacBook Air itself is damaged.
- If you use Boot Camp, you may not be able to boot natively into
  supported versions of Microsoft Windows XP or Windows Vista operating
  systems installed on external USB hard drive.

### Additional Information

If you're using an external USB hub with several connected USB devices, the external USB storage device you wish to start from may not be recognized, or, may need to be connected directly into one of the computers USB ports instead.  Some computer keyboards that include USB ports may not supply enough power to some external USB hard drives.

Tip: If your USB device isn't working, try following the troubleshooting steps here.

Comment: trouble shooting steps where?

Comment: A good answer, but since the OP wants to run a DOS program, I don't think it will actually solve his problem.  Does Boot Camp allow running DOS on a Macintosh?

Answer (score 1):

1 Use disk utility to 'restore' the image of the USB stick to a .dmg file.
2 Repartition the USB stick using partition type GUID.
3 Use disk utility to 'restore' the .dmg back to the USB stick.
4 Go to system preferences->startup disk, select the USB stick, and then select 'reboot'.

Comment: I don't think DOS will be able to boot from a GUID disk.

Answer (score 0):

If Samsung can't provide you with a Macintosh solution, your best bet is to borrow a friend's PC and temporarily install the SATA drive in it.